# Не отображается progressbar на android 10

Tags: java, android

Не отображается progressbar на android 10.
На версиях android ниже работает.

Progressbar расположен на кнопке. В момент отправки запроса текст на кнопке убирается, а вместо него появляется прогрессбар. Сам progressbar:

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailSignInButton"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/emailSignInButton"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:indeterminateTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

Теперь отображение в активити:

```
private void signIn(String email, String password) {
            if (!validateForm()) {
            return;
        }

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //**этот момент не работает**
        emailSignInButton.setText("");

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this,"Вход выполнен",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            updateUI(user);
                            Intent i = new Intent(EmailPasswordActivity.this, CommonListObjects.class);
                            startActivity(i);
                            EmailPasswordActivity.this.finish();
                        } else {
                           Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Аутентификация пользователя не выполнена", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            updateUI(null);
                                       }
                 
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        emailSignInButton.setText("ВОЙТИ");
                       
                    }
                });
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте поиграть с "android:elevation" вашего ProgressBar, например увеличить до 10dp.

Comment: могу посоветовать либу с прогресс баром, которую я использую) как раз для входа в приложение) будет меньше танцев с бубном)

Comment: У вас `android:indeterminate="false"` - и нет назначения прогресса конкретного. В итоге, возможно, оно отображается, просто вы ничего не видите, т.к. прогресс установлен в 0. Попробуйте поменять на `android:indeterminate="true"`

Comment: У вас разметка немного странная. Возможно дела в том, что высота прогресса зависит от высоты кнопки и когда она невидима, высота 0 у обоих элементов. Попробуйте кнопку невидимой делать через INVISIBLE а не GONE

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Вы правы были, установив `android:indeterminate="true"` progressBar стал отображаться корректно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас `android:indeterminate="false"` - и нет назначения прогресса конкретного. В итоге, возможно, оно отображается, просто вы ничего не видите, т.к. прогресс установлен в 0. Попробуйте поменять на `android:indeterminate="true"`